# How to remove duplicate unseparated words in a string?

Tags: python

```
string1 = "calvin kleinklein design dress"
```

How can I remove the second duplicate "klein"?

The result should look like:

```
string2 = "calvin klein design dress"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to include some code for your efforts based on your own research

Comment: Tokenize your raw strings. Apply some rule (based on your specific criteria) to identify your "duplicate" word tokens, then make them singular.

Comment: You would need to split the string up into individual words, then check each one of those to see if its first half was equal to its second half. Unclear how you would want to handle a something like "booboob" though…

Answer (score -1):

```
string1 = "calvin kleinklein design dress"
list1 = string1.split(" ")
list2 = []
for i in list1:
    if len(i)%2 == 0: 
        if i[:(len(i)//2)] == i[(len(i)//2):]:
            a = i[0:len(i)//2]
            list2.append(a)
        else:
            list2.append(i)
    else:
        list2.append(i)

str2 = ' '.join(list2)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Before answering, please try to ask clarification questions in the question with the user. And also ask for what they've already tried. Also try to explain briefly what you did together with the code. Hope you enjoy this wonderful community.